# Plot data by selection data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large dataset of  country's scale streamflow stations ordered as it is shown in the table. My experience in R language is beginner.

"CODE" represents streamflow stations name, and

"VAL" the streaflow value in m^3/sec.

All the timeseries for each of the stations ranges from 1/1/2002 to 31/12/2012.

Data Sample
[image]

I'd like to plot **by selecting** a specific "CODE" from the whole timeseries to see in line plot format the whole timeseries and as a second step to see a monthly analysis for this station in boxplot format.
No colors or other ploting effects.

/edit

What I've tried till now is the following script

```
library("gdata")

library("ggplot2")

timeseries <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\G\\Documents\\R\\Projects\\...\\...\\....csv", header = T)

summary(timeseries)

plot(timeseries$VAL ~ timeseries$CODE, col="light blue", pch = 19 , srt=45)

ggplot(table) + geom_point(aes(x= DATE[1:4017], y = VAL [1:4017]))
```

and I took a composite boxplot for all the stations for the first plot

and the ggplot didn't worked

**//Final edit number after scoa solution**

```
    library("gdata")
    library("scales")
    library("ggplot2")
    timeseries<- read.csv("C:\\Users\\G\\Documents\\R\\Projects\\...\\...\\......csv", header = T)
    timeseries$DATE <- as.Date(as.character( timeseries$DATE),format = "%d/%m/%Y")

ggplot(data= timeseries[timeseries$CODE == "StationA",]) + geom_point(aes(x= DATE, y = VAL)) + scale_x_date(breaks= date_breaks("1 month"))
```

[Result](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23801982/R_forums/Rplot03.jpeg)

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Also, please post what you've tried already. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subset your `data.frame` in `data` rather than `aes`, make sure your `DATE` variable is in the right format, and use `scale_x_datetime()`.

```
timeseries$DATE <- as.Date(as.character(timeseries$DATE),format = "%d/%m/%Y")

library(scales)

ggplot(data=timeseries[timeseries$CODE == "a",]) + 
    geom_point(aes(x= DATE, y = VAL)) +
    scale_x_date(breaks= date_breaks("1 month"))
```

You may want to change the default value for `date_breaks()` to `"3 months"` or `"6 months"` because the axis labels are difficult to read.

Comment: This gives the time series in a "per year" format with overlapping years

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23801982/Rplot02.jpeg

Comment: @ scoa : "Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only"

Comment: @GeoBar then transform your date `timeseries$DATE<- as.POSIXct(timeseries$DATE)`. There is not much we can do to help you without the data

Comment: @ scoa
Here is a sample
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23801982/R_forums/Sample_streamflows.csv

it contains in station C some duplicates but it's not a problem

Comment: @ scoa 
Thanks a lot !!!
 I will update the whole code in order to be just and the question as solved